# PHP mysqli echo text elsewhere when typing

Tags: php, echo

Hi is there any way in PHP when if I start typing in a text field that whatever is being typed gets echoed out in real time somewhere else on a page?

Comment: Javascript is a reasonable client-side language for this task.  However, I don't understand why your question is asking about mysqli.  Have you done any research on this task?  Have you attempted to code anything yet?  What is the benefit of this effect that you are hoping to enjoy?  Are you hoping to show "rich" text from raw input text?  Are you asking about displaying the text elsewhere on the **same** page or on **another** page/device?

Comment: @mickmackusa I'll explain what I'm trying to do. I have two input text fields. One is  to add a title, the other is to add a url permalink. Idea would be typing in the title field and would eco out into the permalink field except I would use str_replace and stretolower to automatically generate it.

Comment: Please add all relevant question details to your question so that the full story is all in one predictable place.  (then remove your comment)  Let's see your best coding attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with JQuery. As the text is written in the text box the innerHtml in the div will be updated realtime.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
            var textwritten = $(this).val();
            document.getElementById('copiedText').innerHTML = textwritten;
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="copiedText"></div>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only (_try this_) answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa Is this any better?

Comment: Something is ALWAYS better than nothing.  Frankly, putting forth this extra effort only yields better results for you, the OP, and StackOverflow.  This makes you look smarter, this helps the OP to understand how/why your answer works, it helps SO to be a more comprehensive resource, and helps Search Engines to find this page.

Answer (score 0):

YES you can do that by using websockets and listening to them ,you need to keep a text monitor that reads the changes in a certain file or any stream and use sockets to push data to frontend or whichever module you want it to go.

You can look into https://socket.io/ documentation for more information.They even have few live examples.